# how to refresh ionic 4 list items after deleting an element

Tags: javascript, ionic4

what I want to do is refresh ionic 4 list items after deleting an element, because i'm getting the error below:

html:

```
 <ion-list [hidden]="showAllStations==false">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of wayPoints; let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{item.location}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox slot="start" 

        (ionChange)="delete(i)"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-button  type="submit" (click)="deletStations()" expand="block" class="ion-text-center ion-margin-top" >Valide</ion-button>

    </ion-list>
```

ts:

```
 delete(index){

 console.log(index);
 this.deletedStations.push(index);
 // delete this.wayPoints[index];
 console.log(this.deletedStations);
}
 deletStations(){
  this.deletedStations.forEach(index => delete this.wayPoints[index]);
  console.log(this.wayPoints);
  this.modalCtrl.dismiss(this.wayPoints);
 }
```

error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

Comment: You should refresh your list after deletion.

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: Where are you assigning value to this.wayPoints ?

Comment: from another page

Comment: but I call this.modalCtrl.dismiss(this.wayPoints); to send  wayPoints

Comment: So on another page assign this value(which you are sending on modal dismiss) to  wayPoints again.

Comment: but the problem which I'm facing is in the current page, when I click deletStations(), I got the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
    delete(index){
      this.wayPoints.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

you should simply remove the item from an array using the above method and your array will automatically be updated and changes will be reflected on the frontend in the list and in that case you don't need to refresh the list manually.
GOOD LUCK :)

Answer (score 0):

{this.responselist.splice(this.index,1); }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.